# Конвертация Excel to PDF на C#

Tags: c#, excel, конвертация, windows-server-2012

Есть документ Excel, который необходимо сохранить в PDF. Пробовал использовать Office Interop, но видимо из-за того что у меня Windows Server 2012, оно и не работает. Запускается процесс Excel, и дальше ничего не происходит. Какие есть еще варианты конвертации файла Excel в PDF? Желательно с сылочкой или примером кода.

Comment: Вам нужно руками в Excel или программное решение?

Comment: Конечно программное, но уже его сделал с помощью платной сборки Aspose.Cells for .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я встречал хорошее платное решение – Aspose.Cells for .NET, рекомендую его.

Когда-то 1Ска не умела сохранять эксельный файл как PDF и я городил отдельный сервис по конвертации.

По-моему это одна из лучших рекомендаций для конвертора, которая только может быть: у меня не было проблем с бухгалтерией по этим платёжкам. Кто знает, насколько требовательны некоторые банки к "миллиметр не туда на платёжке – скандал" тот меня поймёт.

Перепробовал при выборе с десяток различных решений (как платных, так и бесплатных), но в итоге убедил начальство, что того стоит. И правда - несколько лет проработало без особых проблем, пока в 1С не добавили штатно работу с экспортом платёжек в Excel.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрел сейчас у меня в CRM системе уже есть это решение. Буду пробовать на нем, ибо Interop не работает к сожалению(((

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло решение с библиотекой Aspose.Cell. По сути то же самое что и Interop, только платное.

Comment: Кстати, а не было проблем при такой конвертации с маленьким масштабом и автоматическом увеличением ячеек таблицы?

Comment: @AndreySherman Нет, не было. Это же банковские документы, там бы на миллиметр влево сразу бы начали бы жаловаться.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй novaPDF. Отличное средство - пользую десяток лет уже. Правда не автоматизировал - не было нужды. Но у них есть SDK.

http://www.novapdf.com/pdf-toolkit.html
http://www.novapdf.com/samples-sdk.html
.

Answer (score 0):

А разве просто сохранить без сторонних программ невозможно?

Для обычных файлов использовала:
"Сохранить как" - выбрать тип файла PDF - Оптимизация Стандартная. В параметрах указать сохранить лист или всю книгу.

Подробнее показано по ссылке: http://www.myexcel.today/kak-preobrazovat-fajl-excel-v-pdf/

Comment: ох да, для обычных файлов использовала: 
"сохранить как" - выбрать тип файла PDF - Оптимизация Стандартная. В параметрах указать сохранить лист или всю книгу.

Comment: Нужна автоматизация этого процесса. Система может генерировать документы на основе шаблонов только в XLS. Надо чтобы это был pdf. Соответственно ручной вариант не подходит.